# How to calculate integration with undefined functions?

Tags: symbolic, integral-equations

There are two functions inside the integral symbol, one is related to the independent variable and the other is independent of the independent variable.

Both are the derivative and Tload is a constant.

How to get the result of integration?
[image]

The correct result should be like this

[image]

Comment: Make use of coordinates: e.g. Integrate[Cross[{t1'[x], t2'[x], t3'[x]}, {a1, a2, a3}], x] works.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Yes, it works. But it is not general.
Are there any other ways that can integrate the derivative of an undefined function?

Answer (score 1):

You can get pretty close by taking the cross out of the integral and use indefinite integration, then apply your limits.

$\left(\int tc'(\xi ) T{\text{load}} \, d\xi \right)\times u'(s)$

as

```
f[ξ_] = Cross[Integrate[Tload tc'[ξ], ξ], u'[s]]
(*Cross[Tload*tc[ξ], u'[s]]*)
```

Then apply the limits

```
f[L] - f[s]

Cross[Tload*tc[L], u'[s]] - Cross[Tload*tc[s], u'[s]]
```

Mathematica will not further simplify without knowing more about the functions involved.

Older versions of Mathematica such as M8 will do definite integrals of derivatives, but newer versions are more careful, since if the integrand is not continuous, blindly applying limits will often end up with an incorrect result.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answers! It helps a lot.